# Recalculation using values from adjacent rows

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to create a logic that recalculates using data in adjacent rows with Apache Hive or Spark SQL, but I'm not sure how, so I'm asking a question.

```
           12
      11        1
   10               2
9                       3
   8                4
       7        5
            6
```

```
hh  val 
1   5
2   4
3   3
4   2
5   1
6   5
7   4
8   3
9   2
10  1
11  5
12  4
```

The recalculation logic is: Add the values of the two adjacent time zones.
12 o'clock is recalculated to 19 by adding 1 at 10 o'clock, 5 at 11 o'clock, 5 at 1 o'clock, and 4 at 2 o'clock to 4 at 12 o'clock.

It seems simple to do with a program language, but it is difficult to express in SQL.
If anyone knows how to do it, please help.

It could not be expressed as a simple aggregate function (sum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understooed your requirements correctly, but you might consider below approch using a window function

> Add the values of the two adjacent time zones.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 1 hh, 5 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 hh, 4 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 hh, 3 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 hh, 2 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 hh, 1 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 hh, 5 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 hh, 4 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 8 hh, 3 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 9 hh, 3 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 10 hh, 1 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 hh, 5 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 12 hh, 4 val
)
-- query starts here
SELECT hh, val, recalculation FROM (
  SELECT *, SUM(val) OVER w AS recalculation
    FROM (
      SELECT 0 AS day, * FROM sample_table UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS day, * FROM sample_table UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS day, * FROM sample_table
    ) t
  -- below window frame covers adjacent 2 time zones (includes 5 hours).
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY day, hh ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 2 FOLLOWING)
) t 
WHERE day = 1 ORDER BY hh;

-- query result
+----+-----+---------------+
| hh | val | recalculation |
+----+-----+---------------+
|  1 |   5 |            21 |
|  2 |   4 |            18 |
|  3 |   3 |            15 |
|  4 |   2 |            15 |
|  5 |   1 |            15 |
|  6 |   5 |            15 |
|  7 |   4 |            16 |
|  8 |   3 |            16 |
|  9 |   3 |            16 |
| 10 |   1 |            16 |
| 11 |   5 |            18 |
| 12 |   4 |            19 |
+----+-----+---------------+
```